# Deserializing JSON into Object

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I'm deserializing a JSON string into an object. I can't use a `Dictionary<string, string>` because the JSON inside is complex. I know about the `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`, but I'm over the .NET 3.5 framework, so I can't use `dynamic`.

So I ended up here:

```
object json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<object>("myjson");
```

But I see no way to access `json` without reflection. Any tips?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this domain so I apologize if this is a silly question... but why can't you use reflection to access `json.html`?

Comment: I can use, but I think if you see yourself using reflection in the middle of something trivial, you are doing something wrong. In this case, I think Im.

Answer (score 13):

I would use [ServiceStack.Text](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344) and parse it using JsonObject.Parse.

Then you have a Dictionary of data that is easy to read.

ServiceStack is **faster and better** than Json.NET.

Answer (score 10):

This can be done with [ServiceStack's JsonSerializer](http://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/) as easily as:

```
var dictionary = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Dictionary<string,string>>(myJson);
```

It's even more concise if you use the Extension methods:

```
var dictionary = myJson.FromJson<Dictionary<string,string>>();
```

Otherwise if you prefer you can use the dynamic API:

```
var jsonObj = JsonObject.Parse(myJson);
var value = jsonObj.Get("key");
```

Here are a couple of real-world usages showing the different ways you can deserialize a dynamic JSON payload:

- [Parsing GitHub's JSON response](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/UseCases/GitHubRestTests.cs)
- [Parsing Google Maps JSON Response](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/UseCases/GMapDirectionsTests.cs)
- [Parsing Centroid](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/UseCases/CentroidTests.cs)

As a bonus you'll be using [.NET's fastest JSON serializer](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344) :)

ServiceStack's Json Serializer is also available to download on NuGet with:

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Text
```

Comment: Hi Demis, 
I have a couple of questions  
1. For parsing large json files is there a streaming Json parse option available?  
  2. When the Json is embedded inside square bracket [], the parsing fails is there any method available to override it?

Comment: 1) No. 2) I don't understand the example, but all the parsing hooks + customization's that are available are on `JsConfig` and `JsConfig<T>`

Comment: Thank You, Demis. I got the following error "SerializationException: Type definitions should start with a '{', expecting serialized type 'RootObject', got string starting with: ]" when trying to parse the json object present [Link-here](http://pastebin.com/WZTSbYNJ). When I remove the first character in the file [ and the last character ] in the file, then I am able to parse successfully.

Answer (score 1):

[JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) is a popular JSON serialization library, it allows you to serialize your typed objects [to](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Serialize.htm)/[from](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Deserialize.htm) JSON as well as get typed representations of the meta-structure (through the [`JObject` class](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)) for when you don't know the structure of your JSON.

I've found it to be better than the offerings that .NET comes with out-of-the-box for JSON many times over.