# deserialize json using construtor with servicestack

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have an immutable object that I serialized into json using servicestack's framework. Now I want to deserialize this json string into real object. But my object is immutable.

Is there a way to tell servicestack json deserializer to use the constructor ? I don't want to add a public set in my properties.

I find a way to do it using Newtonking Json Deserializer, but is there a equivalent in servicestack ?
http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConstructorAttribute.htm

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a simple config that will enable this, but you could write a custom deserializer easily enough:

```
JsConfig<MyRequestClass>.DeSerializeFn = jsonString => {
    var obj = JsonObject.Parse(jsonString);
    return new MyRequestClass(obj.Get("PropertyA"), obj.Get("PropertyB"), ...);
}
```

See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8043207/795339) for more info.

Comment: thanks for your solution. I don't really like the idea to remap each property of my class. I don't understand why using servicestack, it's really easy to serialize my immutable object using ToJson() method, but when I want to deserialize it, I need a map manually each property. My current workaround is to use the json framework from Newton with JsonConstructor attribute

Comment: I think the problem here is a conflict with the [design philosophy of ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Advantages-of-message-based-web-services). The ideal is to have DTO classes specifically designed for your request/response classes. So an alternative approach here would be to create separate classes with writeable properties for deserialization, then map the DTO object to your immutable object at the service layer.